# Replacing scribe scroll for a wizard

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, character-creation, house-rules, wizard

Is there any canon way to replace scribe scroll with a different feat as a wizard without also losing the later bonus wizard feats/familiar?

If no, would there be a foreseeable balancing issue if replacing scribe scroll with a metamagic, spellcasting, or bonus wizard feat applicable at level 1?

(Barring the dark chaos feat shuffle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to point out that *Scribe Scroll* is quite useful for a prepared Spellcaster. There are a lot of situational spells (such as *Identify*) that you will not memorize every day but which may come handy; *Scribe Scroll* help you prepare for that!

---

With that out of the way, unfortunately Wizards Alternative Class Features tend to focus on getting rid of the *Familiar*; still I found two outliers:

- *"Combat Wizard"*, an unnamed ACF from *Unearthed Arcana*, p. 59, trades away *Scribe Scroll* and *Metamagic* bonus feats for *Fighter* feats. You can grab *Improved Initiative* at level 1.
- *Eidetic Spellcaster* (*Dragon #357*, p. 89), trades away *Scribe Scroll* (OR your *Familiar*) for the amazing ability to memorize all spells instead of writing them down into a spellbook. You still need to (1) prepare the spells to be able to cast them and (2) pay the usual price to learn them (paying for incense instead of ink).

For completeness, as you mentioned, the *Dark Chaos Shuffle Feat* (*Embrace the Dark Chaos* followed by *Shun the Dark Chaos*) is also available to trade it away for another feat.

Comment: Are you sure *Eidetic* is Scribe OR Familiar? I thought it was both? (I'm relying on second-hand quotes though, I haven't seen the original).

Comment: @Adeptus: Exact quote: ***Replaces:** If you select this class feature you do not gain a familiar or the Scribe Scroll bonus feat.* I would note that all other ACFs from the page 88/89 trade away the familiar, this one is the only one offering a choice.

Comment: Might be a failing of the english language.  Saying "You do not gain prizes behind door #1 or door #2" to me seems to be both not a choice.  But I can read it both ways.  Probably a distinct Q in itself=)

Comment: @joedragons: Oh! I hadn't thought about that! I would use **nor** myself to deny both, and reserve *or* for giving the alternative, so it didn't occur to me some may consider this ambiguous, and now I am doubting...

Answer (score 1):

As written, the [Enhanced Summoning](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/specialistWizardVariants.htm#enhancedSummoning) ACF for specialist Conjurers also gives up the bonus feats.

But, a generous DM might let you take each substitution as a separate item.
1st level, swap Scribe Scroll for Augmented Summoning.
5th & 10th levels, keep the bonus feats.

> **Enhanced Summoning (Ex)**
>   At 1st level, a conjurer using this variant gains the Augmented Summoning feat for free instead of the Scribe Scroll feat.
>
> At 5th level, the conjurer's summoned creatures become particularly tough to dispel. Add 2 to the DC of any caster level check made to dispel the conjurer's summoned creatures. At 15th level, this addition to the DC increases to 4.
>
> At 10th level, the conjurer's summoned creatures gain an additional +2 bonus to Strength and Constitution. At 20th level, these bonuses increase to +4. These bonuses stack with those granted by the Augmented Summoning feat.
>
> A conjurer using this variant does not gain bonus feats for advancing as a wizard.